# Ruby on rails: Change flash message colour without Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to ask if there is any way to change the appearance of flash messages without using Twitter Bootstrap?

Here's my views: .index.html.erb

```
<form class="login-form" action="/login" id="login-form" method="post" >
  <h2 class="login-title">Sign In</h2>
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
  <% end -%>
```

And my controller as follows:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    # If the user exists AND the password entered is correct.
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
    # login code comes here
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

How do I style my error flash message without using Twitter Bootstrap?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can add your own css classes for that

Comment: No offense, but this is one very confused question… I'm somewhat at a loss where to even begin answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign a css class to the flash message, and style it appropriately:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="custom-alert">
    <%= msg %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And in your appropriate stylesheet:

```
.custom-alert {
  background-color: #d96459;
}
```

If you want to assign various custom alert classes based off of the flash name, you can define a helper to conditionally output a class name and embed that into the class name in the markup:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def alert_class(flash_name)
    if flash_name == "success"
      return "success-class"
    elsif flash_name == "error"
      return "error-class"
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
end

# And then in your markup:

<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class=<%= name %>>
    <%= msg %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps!